# I am made of ice but hot as fire

Tags: riddle

> I am made of ice but hot as fire, I am soft but hard as rock

No other context to this riddle. What is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is:

> [IcyHot](https://www.icyhot.com/)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liniment):

> IcyHot is a line of liniments produced and marketed by Chattem, now a subsidiary of Sanofi. Mentholatum Ointment, branded Deep Heat outside of the US was introduced in December 1894 and is still produced today with numerous variations.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is

> **dry ice**.

Explanation:

> I burn human skin. I am hard but easily broken.